# Reading Multiline JSON File in spark comes in one row

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a json file like below -

```json
{
  "249": "\"Other\"",
  "63": "\"Billing\"",
  "67": "\"Handset\"",
  "72": "\"Your plan\"",
  "71": "\"Customer services\"",
  "69": "\"Network coverage\"",
  "68": "\"International roaming\"",
  "770": "\"Purchases\"",
  "70": "\"Expectations not being met\"",
  "65": "\"Fraud\""
}
```

I am reading this file using multiline spark.read method -

```
val df = sqlContext.read.option("multiline","true").json("file:///category_names.json")
```

Dataframe read is :

```
+---------------------------+---------+-------+---------+-----------------------+------------------+----------------------------+-------------------+-----------+-----------+
|249                        |63       |65     |67       |68                     |69                |70                          |71                 |72         |770        |
+---------------------------+---------+-------+---------+-----------------------+------------------+----------------------------+-------------------+-----------+-----------+
|"Other (none of the above)"|"Billing"|"Fraud"|"Handset"|"International roaming"|"Network coverage"|"Expectations not being met"|"Customer services"|"Your plan"|"Purchases"|
+---------------------------+---------+-------+---------+-----------------------+------------------+----------------------------+-------------------+-----------+-----------+
```

I want to join this dataframe with another dataframe where column name here is a primary key there. I want the output in the below format

```
CategroryID CategoryName
249           "Other"
63            "Billing"
```

Is there a spark way of doing this? I can pivot the dataframe but i am looking for a better way to do this.

Comment: Convert columns to array and then explode

Comment: can you add more details please. maybe a link

Comment: blackbishop was a great help! Thanks you too for helping, I'm curious to know your POV if you agree that this is the most straightforward way of doing this.

Comment: If your json schema is really that simple, perhaps you can read it as .csv (using DROPMALFORMED mode?) to get two columns right out of the gate.

Comment: forgetting the JSON, bb's option is better as it is shorter but he was already there, so i looked at an alternative - which is longer

Answer (score 2):

Use [`stack`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/#stack) function to unpivot the dataframe. You can dynamically generate the stack expression from column names list:

```
val stackExpr = s"stack(${df.columns.size}," + df.columns
  .flatMap(c => Seq(c, s"`$c`"))
  .mkString(",") + ") as (CategroryID, CategoryName)"

//stackExpr: String = stack(10, 249,`249`,63,`63`,65,`65`,67,`67`,68,`68`,69,`69`,70,`70`,71,`71`,72,`72`,770,`770`) as (CategroryID, CategoryName)

val df1 = df.selectExpr(stackExpr)

df1.show()

//+-----------+--------------------+
//|CategroryID|        CategoryName|
//+-----------+--------------------+
//|        249|             "Other"|
//|         63|           "Billing"|
//|         65|             "Fraud"|
//|         67|           "Handset"|
//|         68|"International ro...|
//|         69|  "Network coverage"|
//|         70|"Expectations not...|
//|         71| "Customer services"|
//|         72|         "Your plan"|
//|        770|         "Purchases"|
//+-----------+--------------------+
```

---

Another way by creating map column from each row then explode it:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.map

val mapExpr = map(df.columns.flatMap(c => Seq(lit(c), col(c))):_*)
val df1 = df.select(explode(mapExpr).as(Seq("CategroryID", "CategoryName")))
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked now :) 
However, i have to ask, is this the best way to do this? Can't there be a way to get in this format while reading from the JSON? Something like setting inferSchema = false and providing struct schema

Comment: @Shiv No, there is no other way, when your read JSON using spark, the keys are always loaded as columns. So either you fix the process that generates the JSON file or transform it after your read in spark.

Answer (score 0):

For academic purposes and me refreshing my skills so now and again, an alternative - but you will need to rename cols etc. as I just used my own and assumed the DF is there and not addressing JSON:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val df   = sqlContext.createDataFrame(Seq(("xxx", "yyy", "zzz"))).toDF("v1", "v2", "v3")
val cols = df.columns
val df2  = df.withColumn("arrayColNames", array(cols.map(lit):_*))
             .withColumn("arrayColVals",  array(cols.map(df(_)):_*))

val df3 = df2.withColumn("arrayNamesVals", arrays_zip(col("arrayColNames"), col("arrayColVals")));
val df4 = df3.withColumn("aNV", explode($"arrayNamesVals"))
val df5 = df4.select($"aNV.*")    
df5.show(false)
```

returns:

```
+-------------+------------+
|arrayColNames|arrayColVals|
+-------------+------------+
|v1           |xxx         |
|v2           |yyy         |
|v3           |zzz         |
+-------------+------------+
```

Comment: Shorter and less complicated maybe: `df.select(array(df.columns.map(c => struct(lit(c).as("name"), col(c).as("value"))):_*).as("col")).selectExpr("inline(col)").show`

Comment: @blackbishop  I don't  work as coder for a while and indeed I was remiss in the simpliifcation... c => ...  for combining...