# Load spark data frame from a pretty-printed text file

Tags: json, dataframe, scala, apache-spark, pretty-print

I have a thousands of json files, and the content within each file is similar to the following:

```
{
"1" : { "key":"key1", "val":"val1" },
"2" : { "key":"key2", "val":"val2" },
"3" : { "key":"key3", "val":"val3" }
.
.
.
}
```

What is the proper way to load those files into a spark dataframe so as a result i will have

```
+------+----------------------------------+
|id    | val.                             |
+------+----------------------------------+
|1     | { "key":"key1", "val":"val1" }   |
|2     | { "key":"key2", "val":"val2" }   |
|3     | { "key":"key2", "val":"val2" }   |
+------+----------------------------------+
```

I 'v tried to load the json as multiline

```
val df= spark.read.option("multiline","true").json(small_file)
```

but the result was one row and three columns

```
+------------------------+------------------------+----------------+
|1                       |2                       |3               |
+------------------------+------------------------+----------------+
|{ "key":"key1", "val..} ||{"key":"key2", "val..} |{"key":"key3"...|
+------------------------+------------------------+----------------+
```

What i did also was loading the files into a Map

```
 val keys = df.columns
 val values = df.collect().last.toSeq
 val myMap = keys.zip(values).toMap
 
 println(myMap)
 // output
 // Map(1-> [key1, val1], 2-> [key2, val2], 3-> [key3, val3])
```

But i did not figure how to create a dataframe from this Map

Comment: What are all the "_traditional methods_" you tried? where is your code?

Comment: Read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70838259/reading-multiline-json-file-in-spark-comes-in-one-row, post some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to achieve the result using the following steps:

As mentioned in the question , the result df after loading will look like

```
+------------------------+------------------------+----------------+
|1                       |2                       |3               |
+------------------------+------------------------+----------------+
|{ "key":"key1", "val..} ||{"key":"key2", "val..} |{"key":"key3"...|
+------------------------+------------------------+----------------+
```

1- Cast the columns to string

```
val cols=df.columns.map(x => col(s"${x}").cast("string").alias(s"${x}"))
```

2- Create a columns string

```
val str_cols=df.columns.mkString(",")
```

3- Create a new df using the casted values in step1

```
val df1 = df.withColumn("temp",
                        explode(arrays_zip(array(cols:_*),
                        split(lit(str_cols),","))))
                        .select("temp.*")
                        .toDF("vals","index")
```

4- the resulted dataframe will be like whats needed

```
df1.select($"index",$"vals").show()
+------+----------------------------------+
|index | vals                             |
+------+----------------------------------+
|1     | { "key":"key1", "val":"val1" }   |
|2     | { "key":"key2", "val":"val2" }   |
|3     | { "key":"key2", "val":"val2" }   |
+------+----------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

That is a multiline JSON file, you can read such file specifying the `multiline` option like this:

```
val spark = SparkSession
  .builder()
  .appName("JSONReader")
  .master("local")
  .getOrCreate()

val multiline_df = spark.read.option("multiline","true")
  .json("multiline-file.json")

multiline_df.show(false)
```

The result will be something like this:

```
[info] +------------+------------+------------+
[info] |1           |2           |3           |
[info] +------------+------------+------------+
[info] |[key1, val1]|[key2, val2]|[key3, val3]|
[info] +------------+------------+------------+
[info]
```